# How to automatically download files from a website to a folder

Tags: jquery, ajax, download

What would be the best way to do **automatic download files** (i.e files that are regularly being updated) from a website, and put those files in a local folder on my windows machine?

Do you use Ajax, or is plain jQuery good enough?

Can anyone hint me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: These are completely wrong technologies for what you want to do, also you may want to provide more details such  as what the actual files are etc.

Comment: The files are in a proprietary format...They just need to be downloaded automatically and put into a folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the url of the files, you can make an GET request and download files.

This GET request can be made using Ajax w/o Jquery or a simple HTTP program which make the requests and downloads it.

Freely usable programs such as wget are also present.

Comment: cool, thank you. I managed to get WGET working. Any ideas on how I can run a cron job with it? So that it will automatically download a file once a week at a certain time?