# Auto download a file from URL in PHP?

Tags: php

If I have a HTML page that generates a URL that leads to an .mp4 file, how can I use PHP to download that file to the clients computer? The user can right-click the link and select 'Save As', but I want this to happen straight away. The file will likely be over 200mb, so I don't want the server to have to download it first. The file is not on the server, it's at a remote address. Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269573/how-to-automatically-download-files-from-a-website-to-a-folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically download files from a website to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269573/how-to-automatically-download-files-from-a-website-to-a-folder)

Comment: @segFault linked q is not at all the same as this one. That one has user wanting to download from server. This one has a server trying to create a link that will cause a user to auto-download from a different server

Comment: @RussJ linked q is about something completely different

Comment: Benji, why is a simple link not enough? If the remote server sets content-type correctly, left-clicking on the link will automatically play or download, depending on the client's preference. The content will never go through your server.

Comment: @jhnc it's really just for convenience. The site in question is working as a proxy video downloader, so it would be nice if a user could just paste in a link, click go and get the 'save as' prompt. Obviously a link works just as well, it's just more clicks.

Comment: Isn't returning a 302 enough to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Simply send a HTTP redirect to the original URL:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily');
header('Location: http://example.org/file.mp4');
```